# Giving illogical compilation errors for console.log() (Angular 13.0.1)

Tags: angular, typescript

I was just following an udemy tutorial when suddenly, these errors appeared: `Unexpected keyword or identifier.`, `Member 'console' implicitly has an 'any' type.`, `Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.`, `'log', which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type.`, `Identifier expected.`. Here's my line 10 code: `console.log('example');`

Can someone explain what happened?

Edit: Here's my code:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HardcodedAuthenticationService {

  constructor() { }

  console.log('example');

  authenticate(username: any, password: any) {
    if (username !== '' && password !== '') {
      sessionStorage.setItem('authenticatedUser', username)
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  isUserLoggedIn() {
    let user = sessionStorage.getItem('authenticatedUser');
    return !(user === null)
  };
}
```

Comment: Move this console call inside constructor or method or outside of class

Comment: sorry, it should be in authenticate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.log()` needs to be put in a function/method. Because of `log`'s nature, it cannot be run outside of a function/method.